# Next.js pages using Link module not loading files with CSS import

Tags: reactjs, next.js, css-loader

I'm adding next.js (7.0.2) to an existing project and can't figure out why the Link module isn't loading pages that have `import 'style.css'`.

I have followed the [@zeit/next-css](https://github.com/zeit/next-plugins/tree/master/packages/next-css) instructions and also the [Next.js/Express](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/server-side-support-for-clean-urls/create-a-custom-server) integration.

I installed the following packages

- next 7.0.2
- @zeit/next-css
- css-loader@1.0.1
- express (v4)

next.config.js

```
    // ./next.config.js file
    const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css')
    module.exports = withCSS()
```

index.js

```
    // ./pages/index.js file
    import Link from 'next/link'
    const Index = () => (
      <div>
        <p>Hello Next.js</p>
        <p>
          <Link href="/test"><a>test</a></Link>
        </p>
      </div>
    )

    export default Index
```

test.js

```
    // ./pages/test.js file
    import "../style.css"
    export default () => <div className="example">Hello World!</div>
```

style.css

```
    // ./style.css file
      .example {
        font-size: 50px;
      }
```

Expected behavior: The Link module will load pages with CSS just like it would any other page.

Actual behavior: All pages will load EXCEPT the one that has `import 'my.css'`.  I can load that page directly via a url.

EG -

1. Works = loading http://localhost:3000/index
2. Works = loading http://localhost:3000/test (and css is applied)
3. Does NOT work = Load http://localhost:3000/index and click the test link.  Nothing happens.  If I go to the Network tab on the Developer Tools (Chrome) I see test.js listed and the initiator is page-loader.js. This seems to be followed by a series of on-demand-entries-ping?page=/ but not sure what it means.

Update: If I comment out the `import "../style.css"` the file loads (without CSS).  So it seems there is something in the css processing with server side routing that isn't right with my setup.

@Darryl - here are the relevant snippets from my express initialization file.  The entire file can be found (current iteration) at https://github.com/tagyoureit/nodejs-poolController/blob/6.0-DEV/src/lib/comms/server.js#L33.

```
  function startServerAsync(type) {
    ...
    const _next = require('next')
    const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
    ...
    // servers is an object that holds http/https/socketio/mdns and other servers
    // type='http' in current testing
    servers[type].next = _next({ dev }) 
    servers[type].next.prepare()
      .then(() => {
        servers[type].app = express();
        servers[type].server = 
        container.http.createServer(servers[type].app);
        configExpressServer(servers[type].app, express, servers[type].next);
        servers[type].server = servers[type].server.listen(servers[type].port, function () {
        container.logger.verbose('Express Server ' + type + ' listening at port %d', servers[type].port);
        container.io.init(servers[type].server, type)
            resolve('Server ' + type + ' started.');
      });
    }

    // assign static/api routes
    function configExpressServer(app, express, _next) {
      // use next as router
      const handle = _next.getRequestHandler()

      // many app.get / app.use statements
      ...
      // catch all to route through next
      app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        const { parse } = require('url')
        const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true)
        const { pathname, query } = parsedUrl
        handle(req, res, parsedUrl)
      })
  }
```

Comment: Since u said u also did nextjs custom server Express, can u provide your server side file like app.js or something similar?
Also check if there is an error in your dev console.
I guess the problem is related with next/router..

Comment: @DarrylR.Norbert - I added the relevant bits.  It's quite a lot of code as I have many API's and other servers (MDNS/SSDP/etc) that are also started up at the same time.  I'm also not seeing any errors in the dev console or server logs.

Comment: I have discovered this is a known issue in the community and many people are struggling with it.  https://github.com/zeit/next-plugins/issues/282

Answer (score 0):

i had this problem too, after spending much more time finally i've found a solution, first thing you shuold manage your code with layouts and then in any pages that uses layouts you must add : import Link From 'next/link' just After importing layout line. i hope this solves your problem

Comment: strange... but seems working, i will still monitor this and update. Thanks.